# How do I properly use Enums and/or Custom Objects in a plugin environment

Tags: c#

I have an issue I am trying to work around and can't, so I seek your help if possible.

I am working on refactoring a project that ended up being three projects.

Core
Framework (business and data logic)
Activities (plug-in based)

What I am trying to keep from happening is cross-referencing the Activities and Core project.
Since the classes that were once apart of the Core logic are now in the Activities project I am having to duplicate certain things like Enums and helper classes.

Which brings me to my question:

I have a reference to a class that was initially in my Core, it is needed in my Core too. But I also have that class used in my Activities project, but without that reference to my Core project the class isn't found. Same with a few Enums that are being used in my Activities classes but are also used in my Core code.

So to keep from having to reference my Core project in my Activities - is it OK to duplicate these classes and enums in my Activities project? If not what are my other options?

I want to be as correct as possible in this code. It will be looked at by my peers next week.

What would you suggest in this case? Hope I was clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: Why not move all objects that are used by both the Core and the Activities assemblies into their own assembly.  Then Core and Activities can reference that same assembly, and not have to reference each other.

Comment: Can you please properly explain meaning of your projects? You said three projects, but you named only two. Also we don't know what relationship between the projects should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further expand upon my comment above, if you have classes/enums that are used in both the Core and Activies assemblies, move these into their own, separate assembly (a class library - DLL).  Then both Core and Activities can reference that DLL, rather than referencing each other or having duplicate code.

Trivial Example:

```
public static class Helper
{

    // Helper methods
}
```

Have this class be part of a separate DLL (for sake of the example, let's call it Common).  Then in the Core and Activities projects, add a reference to the Common project/DLL, and the appropriate `using Common;` statements as needed.

Now both Core and Activities can use the objects in Common without having to either a) have a reference to the other assembly (which could introduce tight coupling) or b) have duplicate code existing in both Core and Activities.

It also makes maintaining the common code easier, as there's only one place to change it, not two.  And if you add new assemblies in the future, they can also use the Common DLL as needed.

Comment: Excellent point everyone. I believe I will create another assembly and load them into there and reference it in both projects. That is great!

To answer the question on the Core naming and use:

  What we are wanting in the end is the Onion design:
      Core being center
         Framework over that
          Then outer layers like Activities and anything else that can only communicate with the Framework, not the core or each other.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think if you have "code" assembly, then there should not be assembly "core" references that is not .NET or 3rd party assembly. It would be terribly confusing. At least for me.

Comment: Also I think these kind of problems are clear sign of improper separation between assemblies and most probably improper OO design. So I would definitely dig deeper and look for real reason behind this problem.

Comment: Euphonic, this is exactly why we are refactoring the code. It is 3 years old and in need of a rewrite. We went back to design it and have a clear path we believe. The biggest problem is not breaking the current build and usage as we refactor. We have to watch namespace changes and usage and at the same time implement a better design.

Painful, but in the end it will be a much better design.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot duplicate the classes in separate assemblies if there is other, possibly external code that will use those classes. If the classes or enums are defined twice, even though they are exactly the same the CLR will treat them as two completely different types.

It would make sense to me, if you have an assembly that is called "core" that assembly should have code that is going to be used by other assemblies, so I'm not understanding why they can't be defined in core and have activities reference core.

If that is not acceptable, you may want to rename core, and place the reused code in a separate assembly. Then you can reference that in both your existing assemblies, but not force them to reference each other.

Comment: Jay it only lets me mark one answer correct, but your answer along with Tim were spot on. Thanks for the time and help.